# Update a form field to match another form field

Tags: jsf

My Bet:    Win/Lose: ?????

I have a selectOneMenu that can select dollar amounts 1.00-10.00.  When I select an amount (myBetAmt), I want to update an adjacent text field to the same value (winLoseText). When I call pdateWinLoseText(AjaxBehaviorEvent e), the System.out.println() appropriately prints betAmtId.

I need to know how to change winLoseId value to the same as betAmtId?

```
       <h:selectOneMenu id="betAmtId" styleClass="selectOneMenu" style="margin: 7px; font-family: Courier New; font-size: 12px; width: 130px" value="#{hhraMain.myBetAmt}" title="Enter a bet amount">
                <f:selectItems value="#{hhraMain.myBetAmtList}"/>
                <f:ajax event="change" render="winLoseText" listener="#{hhraMain.updateMyWinLoseText}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:outputText id="winLoseLabelId" styleClass="bodyTextMediumRight" style="width: 55px" value="Win/Lose:" />
        <h:inputText id="winLoseId" styleClass="bodyTextMediumLeft" size="8" value="#{hhraMain.winLoseText}" />




    public void updateMyWinLoseText(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
        String str = e.getComponent().getId();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```